# Show first row on top when table data is refreshed

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TRqrToaDAeqXksLpECUR?p=preview) I have a table with two buttons labeled "Set 1" and "Set 2". When the first button is clicked, the table data changes to the first set. When the second button is clicked, the table data changes to the second set.

This works fine, but what I need is that if the user scrolled down, when the data is refreshed then also the first row of the table needs to be set on top. Any ideas how to make this work?

HTML

```
<div style="width:150px;height:80px;border:1px solid gray;overflow-y:auto">
     <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.col}}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 <br>        
 <button ng-click="showSet1()">Set 1</button>
 <button ng-click="showSet2()">Set 2</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctl', function($scope) {

  $scope.showSet1 = function(){
        $scope.items = [ {col:"a1"}, {col:"b1"}, {col:"c1"}, 
                         {col:"d1"}, {col:"e1"}, {col:"f1"},
                         {col:"g1"}];
  };

  $scope.showSet2 = function(){
        $scope.items = [ {col:"a2"}, {col:"b2"}, {col:"c2"}, 
                         {col:"d2"}, {col:"e2"}, {col:"f2"}, 
                         {col:"g2"} ];
  };

  $scope.showSet1();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, you can scroll to particular element using [**`$anchorScroll`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

Here's what you can do. First, add dynamic ID attribute to `<tr>`s like this:

```
<tr id="row{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.col}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then create a function as follows that scrolls to first row:

```
$scope.scrollToTop = function() {
    $location.hash('row0');
    $anchorScroll();
}
```

Then, just call this function from both the functions (i.e. `showSet1` and `showSet2`).

Here's the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZ008rQJTIbiNgX1m7x7?p=preview)