# AngularJS link with hash-tag

Tags: angularjs

Have link http://example.dev/#5667

Have `<div id="5667" >Some 5667 Target</div>`

How to don't replace links to http://example.dev/#/5667 this, and force to work browser like it was without angularjs, just scroll it to target?

Comment: By removing # could work I think. Check my answer. Combined with anchor links, I think they'll work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43489383/4781975

Comment: use `$anchorScroll` to scroll to an id in angular

Comment: Didn't know this thing, well :D

Comment: $anchorScroll  - I used but I need process incoming links, like " http://example.dev/#5667" from outside.

Comment: Here's a [simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42848902/4315380) of how `$anchorScroll` can be used

Comment: @tanmay Absolutely right. There is no need to remove the `#` from URL as suggested by Zooly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) service.

```
$location.hash('myElementId');
$anchorScroll();
```

Will scroll to the first element with ID `myElementId`.

### [Try it on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V68vNiBwaaQe9RVou2lj?p=preview)

Comment: I know, but how could I catch it from url and don't change URL for user?